# get rid of transparency of selected part of png using imagemagic

Tags: windows, command-line, imagemagick

I have this png image with transparency http://s18.postimg.org/d2h2m4yl5/flatten_canvas2.png

I want to get rid of transparency using imagemagick, but only of the selected part and not the whole image.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would suggest you to do is to cut down the portion which I don't want to be transparent and then use :

```
 convert image.png -transparent white result.png
```

or if not perfectly white, then try

```
 convert image.png -fuzz XX% -transparent white result.png
```

where the smaller the %, the closer to true white or conversely, the larger the %, the more variation from white is allowed to become transparent.
For more details check [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#transparent) and [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz).
After applying them I would superimpose that image on the original one. However you can use [Geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Geometry.html) if you want to . But I would prefer the first way only.

Comment: Thanks for giving the idea of cutting it in parts. I approached that way and it fixed my issue.